# I need clarity of facebook canvas app authorization

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, authorization, facebook-canvas

It's not clear to me from the documentation how it's supposed to work. I know that if I'm using the javascript sdk and have an external site that implements facebook login/registration, I can use the facebook plug in that handles that; but I have a canvas app. If I want to have a user authorize my app as soon as they land on my home page. What does that code look like? I'll be using the javascript sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that gives a code example: http://snipplr.com/view/61108/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

Comment: It doesn't give any code examples of how to authorize from within a canvas app. That's what I'm looking for.